# css not working in mvc model how to put path

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, ejs

css not working in mvc model (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUJH0.png)

my css not working in mvc model

Comment: Please provide `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the file `home.ejs` is being called inside the view folder, while your's css folder is inside the assets folder.

Try `<link href="../assets/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in your home.ejs file.

Let me say, that I'm concluding this, based only on the print screen you just shared. MVC frameworks may put in place many file rules that may be inducing the issue. In that case, lots of debuging should be necessary.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.